# Making Unity Dash open with the last used Lens as the active Lens

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

Especially with no keyboard shortcuts for custom-installed Lenses, I thought it would be nice for the Dash to always open the last used Lens for me (instead of the default Home/Global Lens). Is it possible to achieve this?

Generalization:
Maybe the Dash interaction could be enhanced to make it more keyboard-friendly overall.

As a keyboard-centric user, I find the following flow slightly irksome:

Keyboard :: To open the Dash via the Super key THEN Mouse :: To select the desired lens. (Control-Tab is tedious with 10+ lenses installed) THEN Keyboard :: To type my query THEN Mouse :: To select the desired result. (Cursor keys are difficult when there are a lot of search results).

Just a thought.

Comment: I filed an issue about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/946019  However the issue was marked invalid because I was told to create a Brainstorm idea.  So I did, but that idea was marked as not-an-idea, because people are not permitted to make suggestions regarding Unity there.  Apparently, we have to go directly to the Atyana folks...so I tried that and they said they're not taking general input from people unless a launchpad issue has been filed.  OMFG!!!

Comment: Look at [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186598/unity-dash-lens-auto-completion-based-on-recent-search-strings), where I was asked to file a bug report, but the [Reporting Bugs guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) seems to suggest I should submit it to Brainstorm instead. Thankfully, I haven't gone through with the process. Seems many are happy to simply _close_ open issues, instead of exploring their greater potential.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to the Dconf Editor to change the Unity Lenses.
UbuntuForums.org has some posts about it.
[Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11933218&postcount=17)

The Wiki of Ubuntu.com has also some information about lenses.... and how to build one yourself.. If you have some spare time laying around somewhere, give building a lens a shot.
[wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Lenses/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. We prefer detailed answers here, so can you please elaborate?